# How do use nodejs childprocess exec to run the unix diff command?

Tags: node.js, unix

I need to use node to generate diffs of some files. I have tried the [diff npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff), and while that works great it is much less performant than the version of diff you will find in /usr/bin/.

When I try to use [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to run the diff command it always errors.

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');

var cmd = "diff /path/to/file1.txt /path/to/file2.txt";
childProcess.exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if(error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(stdout);
  }
});
```

The output:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c diff /path/to/file1.txt /path/to/file2.txt
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c diff /path/to/file1.txt /path/to/file2.txt' }
```

If I run the command on the command line myself it works fine.

I've tried running `/usr/bin/diff` instead of just `diff`.

I've tried various different forms of quoting things.

Every other command I have tried, using the exact same files, has worked. `cat`, `wc`, etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Welp, I am answering my own question.

The `diff` command  returns a failure exit code if it finds a difference. Therefore the `console.log(stdout)` call was never being reached. 
If I ignore the error, everything works.

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var cmd = "diff /path/to/file1.txt /path/to/file2.txt";
childProcess.exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

works like a charm.

Comment: Same issue here, I test `stderr` intead

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you.
If you want the code to continue running if there IS a diff and the failure exit code is returned, I wrapped the diff check in a try/catch block so the script can keep running.

Comment: If you use it inside a Promise you need to add `resolve()` in order to resolve the promise.